# Regular Expression for character between brackets

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want a regular expression that matches a ' ' character between brackets and other text:

```
[Hello World]
      ^
```

I've made it this far:

```
\[.* .*\]
```

But unfortunately this also matches this:

```
[HelloWorld] [HelloWorld]
            ^
```

Is there a way to exclude this case?

Comment: What program/language are you using this regex in?

Comment: using it in a find/replace in notepad++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using any amount of wildcard (`.`) characters, use any amount of non-bracket characters:

```
\[[^\]\[]* [^\]\[]*\]
```

This appears very unclear initially, but it breaks down like this:

```
\[            first bracket
[^            exclusion class:
    \]\[          exclude brackets
]*            end exclusion; any amount
              space
[^            exclusion class:
    \]\[          exclude brackets
]*            end exclusion; any amount
\]            final bracket
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
\[([^\]*)\] \[([^\]*)\]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a word boundry?

```
\[.*\b \b.*\]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
\[[^[]]* [^[]]*\]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this (with a space at the end of the find pattern):

```
find: (\[.*?) 
replace: \1
```

(tested on notepad++ 6.3.2)